# How to use "Did" and "Are"?

Tags: auxiliary-verbs

Suppose I need to ask a question like

> "**Did** you change any thing in file"

or

> "**Are** you change anything in file."

Which one is correct. Could any one please give some light how to use **did** and **are** in a similar question?

Comment: “Did you change _anything_ in _the_ file?” is perfect. “_Have_ you changed anything in the file?” is another correct of past tense. But “are” is not used in past tense, but it is used in present tense: “Are you _changing_ anything in the file?”

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Did you change any thing in file

This sentence is grammatically correct

> Are you change anything in file

This sentence is grammatically incorrect. Instead one should use the following sentence **Are you changing anything in file**

The difference between both sentences is that in first you are talking about past while in second you are talking about present.

Comment: Just saying "anything in file" is not correct - *file* is a countable noun, so it has to be *a file* or *the file* or *files*.  I realize this isn't exactly what the OP was asking about, but it is worth pointing out.